# Objects from django are displayed as numbers/ids

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

**UPDATE:**

The original JSON output was this:

```
{ "id": 8
 "user": "k"
 "name": "new"
 "born": "2021-12-06"
 "body_colour": [ 2 ]
 "eye_colour": [ 2 ]
 "image": [ 1 ] }
```

I changed the RatSeralizer to this:

```
class RatSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    user         = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    body_colour  = BodyColourSerializer(many=True)
    eye_colour   = EyeColourSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = rat 
        exclude = ['bio']
```

which changed the JSON output to this, which is what I wanted:

```
{
        "id": 8,
        "user": "k",
        "body_colour": [
            {
                "name": "Fawn"
            }
        ],
        "eye_colour": [
            {
                "name": "Black"
            }
        ],
        "image": [
            {
                "name": "lineart",
                "image": {
                    "small_square_crop": "http://localhost:8000/media/__sized__/images/lineart-crop-c0-5__0-5-50x50.PNG",
                    "thumbnail": "http://localhost:8000/media/__sized__/images/lineart-thumbnail-100x100.PNG",
                    "medium_square_crop": "http://localhost:8000/media/__sized__/images/lineart-crop-c0-5__0-5-400x400.PNG",
                    "full_size": "http://localhost:8000/media/images/lineart.PNG"
                }
            }
        ],
        "name": "new",
        "born": "2021-12-06"
    }
```

That's exactly what I wanted, instead of the numbers it displays the full data (so in the first JSON it said  `"body_colour": [ 2 ]`, now it displays the name of the body colour. So it says `"body_colour": [ { "name": "Fawn" } ]`. BUT, when I try to call this in React, I get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

  27 | 
  28 | componentDidMount() {
  29 |   RatStuff.getRats().then((res) => {
> 30 |     this.setState({ rats: res.data });
     | ^  31 |   });
  32 | }
```

So it seems it isn't currently being read as an array.

---

**Original post:**
I'm using React frontend and Django backend. I've managed to make it so users can add rats to their account, however when I wanna fetch details about the rats the details are displayed as numbers, I'm assuming the id of the detail?

Here's an example. This is what you get if you view one of the rats, frontend-wise:

```
User: 12, Rat Name: newrat Rat Body colour: 3, Eye colour: 3
```

So as you can see, you get the id (?) of each detail except the rat name. It belongs to the user with the id of 12, and the 3rd body colour created, etc.

Here's my models:

```
class EyeColour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class BodyColour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class rat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=132, null =True)
    body_colour = models.ManyToManyField(BodyColour, related_name='bodycolour')
    eye_colour = models.ManyToManyField(EyeColour, related_name='eyecolour')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class EyeColourSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EyeColour
        fields = '__all__' 
        
class BodyColourSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BodyColour
        fields = '__all__' 

class RatSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = rat
        # fields = '__all__' 
        exclude = ['bio']
        # read_only_fields = ['eye_colour', 'body_cdolour']
        expandable_fields = {
            'EyeColour': ('accounts.EyeColourSerializer', {'many': False}),
            'Image': ('accounts.ImageSerializer', {'many': False}),
        }
```

and views:

```
class ratViewset(FlexFieldsMixin, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = RatSerializer
    queryset = rat.objects.all()
```

Finally, this is part of the viewRats.jsx file, the one you access to view each rat:

```
class viewRat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: this.props.match.params.id,
      rat: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RatStuff.getRatById(this.state.id).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ rat: res.data });
    });
  }

....

<div className="row">
              <label> User: </label>
              <div> {this.state.rat.user}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <label> Rat Name: </label>
              <div> {this.state.rat.name}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <label> Rat Body colour: </label>
              <div> {this.state.rat.body_colour}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <label> Eye colour: </label>
              <div> {this.state.rat.eye_colour}</div>
            </div>
```

I'm quite new to this stuff. What am I doing, that makes it display as numbers/the id of each thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the serializer add a serializer field with a `source` attribute for the user. for the many to many fields you have to set many=True which will return an list of all the related serialized objects

```
class EyeColourSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EyeColour
        fields = '__all__' 
    
class BodyColourSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BodyColour
        fields = '__all__' 

class RatSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    user         = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    body_colour  = BodyColourSerializer(many=True)
    eye_colour   = EyeColourSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = rat
        # fields = '__all__' 
        exclude = ['bio']
        # read_only_fields = ['eye_colour', 'body_cdolour']
```

Comment: I tried, but got this error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." Any idea why?

Comment: Tried the user one alone now and that one works at least! So now it displays the username instead of id, thank you :)

Comment: you should be getting an array since you are using a ManytoMany Field in react you have to loop over each item in the array and access the name property.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it. Even in the API list, they're displayed with numbers, like this: `{ "id": 8, "user": "k", "name": "new", "born": "2021-12-06", "body_colour": [ 2 ], "eye_colour": [ 2 ], "image": [ 1 ] }`

Comment: Okay @user14665310 so I tested a bit more. When I use your code, the correct names are displayed in the API list. However, that's when I get the error saying they're not valid as a React child. I'm not sure what to do

Comment: @Kida can you update your question with the error from react and the json output of the api view?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have now updated the post with the original + new json output, and the full new error.

Comment: to access the body_colour you have to use body_colour[0].name

Comment: are you planning on having more than eye colour and body colour for each rat? If you are then you should really use a foreignKey instead of a manyToMany relationship.

Comment: Using body_colour[0].name gives this error instead: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" And yeah, I will be adding more features than eye and body colour. Would using a foreignKey help with this issue, or is it just general best practice?

Comment: a foreign key will solve this issue so that it will work the exact same way as the user. you are probably getting the type error because react is rendering it before the api loads the data try a question mark before the period like this `body_colour[0]?.name`

Comment: Ok, I finally got everything to work. By using your advice, I was able to finally access the data using this: `{this.state.rat.body_colour?.name}`. Using [0] after body_colour kept giving me errors even with the question mark, but body_colour?.name worked :)